# How do we have seperate notifications for different email accounts?

Tags: email, notifications

So I have my Gmail and my work email setup on my WP and so here is the problem.

I really need my phone to make a notification sound when I get a work email but i don't want a sound when I get a new gmail.... way too much spam into that account so it goes off way too often.

Is there a way to set separate notifications for each account. I can't seem to find away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Messaging hub on the Windows Phone can't do this, perhaps in another iteration in the future it could come to existence but until then I don't see any MS way at doing it. When I looked through the Marketplace using several terms like `mail`, `email` or `e-mail` and then combining them with `warning`, `alert` or `reminder` I didn't came across any applications that advertise to do this for you.

> Would like to term myself as a WP developer but, no, not yet.

I guess that's the road you will have to take. Disabling the internal notifications and write your own background application that checks through POP3 / IMAP if there were new mails. To get you started:

- [MSDN - Windows Phone Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(v=vs.92).aspx)
- [MSDN - Background Agents Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=vs.92).aspx)
- [Stack Overflow - Reading e-mail using POP3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp)
- [Stack Overflow - Accessing IMAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp)

I've had a positive experience with developing, so I think you would experience that too. Good luck... :)

Comment: Ah. Haha! :D Yes! Interesting reads there!

Answer (score 3):

I use a workaround for that.  I also have a GMail account, which I use for stuff like internet forums reply notifications and corporate spam which I have actually signed up for.

Instead of adding this low-priority email account as a separate inbox, I forward the email to my main Exchange account on Office 365, where email with that To: address is filed into a folder using rules.  I think you can also get Exchange Online to pull the emails from Gmail, instead of forwarding them, but I have not ever used that feature.

That's what I do for a my personal Hotmail account as well, but the important thing to remember is basically there is no alert when the email is sorted into folders.  You only get alerts for emails coming into the main inbox.

Because getting alerts for sorted emails is desirable when I am at my laptop or desktop computer, I use [an Outlook add-on](http://www.bettasoft.net/mailalert/) which allows that.

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: @AbhishekSha: Just try making rules in GMail to label all incoming email, apart from email you want to be alerted about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible on my Lumia 640 LTE running Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2:

Settings -> Notifications + actions -> *(the account you want to configure)* -> Notification sound