# Is there a single email live tile?

Tags: email, tiles

I have pinned 3 gmail and 1 hotmail mail tiles to the start page. This takes up way too much space, is it possible to just have one "email" tile that will indicate if any inboxes have new mail?

I know that you can link inboxes, but I want to keep the inboxes separate and not merged.

Comment: An answer in a question on notification sounds states that it is not possible http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-do-we-have-seperate-notifications-for-different-email-accounts

Comment: I would also like to add that it is impossible to make a basic application that will list the unread count on a live tile. Developers have no access to information about email account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only 2 options.

1 have seperate inboxes and thus seperate live tiles or link mailboxes to a unified mailbox and get a unified livetile. There is no way to have a linked inbox and in the linked inbox have seperate inboxes again.. thats just how the linked inboxes work.

[how to create a unified mailbox](http://mywpstory.com/2011/07/quick-tip-how-to-create-a-combined-unified-email-inbox-on-windows-phone-7-mango/)